# Self contained deployment .netcore

Tags: .net-core

I'm trying to deploy a .net core 2.2 solution that contains 3 projects in it:

- project one: `App.Cmd` (containing program.cs)
- project two: `App.Core`  (library)
- project three: `App.Core.test`

How can I deploy it as .exe containing everything in order to use it on different computers without using Visual Studio?

I published the `app.Cmd` project in a `.exe` but this `.exe` works only inside this folder (`app.cmd/debug/netcore2.2/publish`)

Whenever I try launching by copy/paste on the desktop, it doesn't work. What do I have to do?

Comment: Are you copying only exe file or whole published folder?

Comment: Can you provide the code to how you're publishing the application?  (What commands you execute)

Comment: It was because I was copying only the .exe file ! Thank you very much